# Time and Auxiliary Space Complexities of .values(), .items(), .keys()

Tags: python, dictionary, time-complexity, big-o, space-complexity

I recently began focusing on the intricacies of Python dictionaries. However, as I began to think a little deeper about the data structure, I encountered several questions––ones that I am struggling to find clear answers for:

What is the time and auxiliary space complexities of `.values()`, `.items()`, and `.keys()`? I have been under the impression that, since they are view objects, they neither require additional space nor additional time to retrieve. In this way, they almost act like pre-set (but dynamic) attributes.

Suppose we had the function `foo` below, which takes a single input dictionary `d`:

```
def foo(d):
    bar = d.values()
```

While this function has space complexity of `O(N)`, where `N` is the number of entries in the dictionary, what is the auxiliary space complexity of this function? In other words, does `d.values()` consume additional space? If it does, the auxiliary space of this function would be `O(N)`. If not, the auxiliary space is `O(1)`.

Likewise, does this function have a time complexity of `O(N)`, where `N` is the number of entries in the dictionary, or does it run in `O(1)` time?

In essence, I am trying to understand the mechanics of a view object. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They all take O(1) time and space. They just return a small view object that internally references the dict, so when you do something with the view object, the view object uses the dict to actually do it.